# TreeView Cells misaligned

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I am having a problem with a treeview in an ASP.NET webapp I am creating. I am using the XenAPI and directly loading the items into the treeview without using a database.

As you can see from the picture below the items in the list are all correct with the one parent node "xenserver-kmmglbto". The problem is that I cannot work out why the preceding cells do not align? I just don't understand why they do not line up correctly and looks so messy?

[image]

```
protected void RefreshTreeView(Session XenSession)
{
    int hostCount = 0;

    List<XenRef<Host>> hostRefs = Host.get_all(CurrentSession);

    foreach (XenRef<Host> hostRef in hostRefs)
    {
        // obtain the full host record from the server
        Host host = Host.get_record(CurrentSession, hostRef);

        TreeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(host.name_label));

        // Get the list of VMs
        List<XenRef<VM>> vmRefs = VM.get_all(XenSession);

        foreach (XenRef<VM> vmRef in vmRefs)
        {
            // get the entire record for each VM.
            VM vm = VM.get_record(XenSession, vmRef);

            if (!vm.is_a_snapshot & !vm.is_snapshot_from_vmpp & !vm.is_control_domain & !vm.is_a_template)
            {
                TreeView1.Nodes[hostCount].ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(vm.name_label));
            }
        }
        hostCount++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I finally worked it out and I feel like an idiot for asking but I spent a long time trying to work it out before posting. :(

```
tr.pager td 
{
}
```

I removed this from my site.css stylesheet and it seems to have fixed it now.